# Read input and return three strings in reverse order (only 1 string so far)

Tags: python, string, function, reverse

```
def rev(one, two, three):
    print("Reverse of the third string is",three[::-1])

# returning concatenation of first two strings
    return one+two

def main():

    # Taking user input of 3 strings
    first = input("Enter first string:")
    second = input("Enter second string:")
    third = input("Enter third string:")


    # calling function, passing three arguments
    print("Reverse of third string is",rev(first, second, third))

main()
```

### Assignment

- Write a Python function that will accept as input three string values
  from a user. The method will return to the user a concatenation of the string values in reverse order. The function is to be called from the main method.
- In the main method, prompt the user for the three strings.

If the input of the strings is Hello, World, and Car, then the output should be raCdlroWolleH

Comment: You seem to have figured out how to reverse a string and concatenate two strings together. What are you asking for help with?

Comment: You know how to reverse a string. You know how to concatenate. You know how to write a function. You know how to get inputs. What is the reason for posting this task here? add all three strings and return them reverted from the function - done.

Comment: I'm struggling to see the problem you are having. I don't know Python so I'm not going to post an answer. If you are looking for a more 'elegant' way to do it just look up stack(abstract data type) Last in first out data structure that is probably in the standard python library. Put all the strings on the stack, pop all strings off the stack.

Comment: kudos = [], kudos.append(1), print(kudos)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your rev function could contain just one line of code (you should call it in the main function). It is as simple as :

`return three[::-1]+two[::-1]+one[::-1]`

Comment: That was it.  You're awesome.  Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is that you're doing two separated prints, one for the first two words and other to the third word. If what you pretende is to join all of the three words and return that, then all you have to do is

New = one + two + three

return New[::-1]